# WatiN insert ReCaptcha Value

Tags: c#, download, browser, captcha, recaptcha

I'm using the WatiN library and want to insert a captcha value into the ReCaptcha value field on the filehoster uploaded.net .
But when I insert the value via:

```
ie.TextField(Find.ById("recaptcha_response_field")).Value = "myCaptcha";
```

The problem is when I insert it the "Download" button won't show. Only if I type something into the field by real typing it shows. 
I already tried:

```
ie.TextField(Find.ById("recaptcha_response_field")).KeyDown('a');
```

but I only get a error.

Can you help me ?

Comment: When stating you "get an error", please always include the actual error text.

Comment: @Jongware True.. I forget that because I was kinda swiftly. I don't know the correct error at the moment because I'm at work. When I'm home I will try to edit the post. My bad